# flutter go_router: how to manually match active path / route?

Tags: flutter, flutter-go-router

Is there a way to manually check with **go_router** (latest version 7.1.1) if a certain path (aka "route") is currently active?

Example: There are 2 paths:

1. "/projects/:id"
2. "/projects/:id/details"

Now I want to check manually if the currently active path is 1) or 2).

Due to the dynamic parameters and the nesting it is not possible to simply compare the currently active path `(goRouterState.location)` with the one to be checked, e.g. with `contains()` or `startsWith()`.
Checking against a regex would be extremely error-prone as well as cumbersome and unnecessary, since go_router can actually handle the matching.

I have not found any functionality of go_router for that.

Since I need this urgently, I am grateful for any tip!

Comment: why do you need to know which route is active? each GoRoute for the route should handle navigating to the right widget and sending the necessary stuff, rather than a widget handling which route it is on

Comment: For business logic beyond pure navigation; here specifically to make more complex checks in the top-level route guard, e.g. redirects depending on the current path or certain actions for routes with a certain prefix.

I know that you can also define the route guard at route-level, but that seems more complex to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at the code of `go_router` and found the function called [`findMatch`](https://github.com/flutter/packages/blob/5933993ef519b67080d2ff50d184bc81d44dc081/packages/go_router/lib/src/parser.dart#LL61C81-L61C81). The function returns a [`RouteMatchList`](https://github.com/flutter/packages/blob/5933993ef519b67080d2ff50d184bc81d44dc081/packages/go_router/lib/src/match.dart#L152)

It's a method of `GoRouteInformationParser` and can be used like this

```
final router = GoRouter.of(context);
final matches = router.routeInformationParser.configuration.findMatch(router.location).matches;
for (final m in matches.reversed) {
  if(m.route is! GoRoute) { // Skip ShellRoute, ...
    continue;
  }
  final route = m.route as GoRoute;
  if (route.name == '/projects/:id/details') { // GoRoute.name must be provided
    return 2;
  }
  // ...
}
```

Hope this helps